# Construction Rakefile to test ports using server-spec - getting 0 examples, 0 failures

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jenkins-pipeline, rakefile, serverspec

In my test scenario, I need to test for ports status on a set of various OS servers. I have constructed my ***Rakefile*** as follow:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

hosts = %w(

    //list of Ux servers
    server1
    //list of Win servers
    server2

)

task :spec => 'spec:all'

namespace :spec do
  task :all => hosts.map {|h| 'spec:' + h.split('.')[0] }
  hosts.each do |host|
    short_name = host.split('.')[0]
    role       = short_name.match(/[^0-9]+/)[0]

desc "Run serverspec to #{host}"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(short_name) do |t|
  ENV['TARGET_HOST'] = host
  t.pattern = "spec/{base,#{role}}/*_spec.rb"
  end
 end
end
```

I then added following in the ***spec_helper.rb***:

```
require 'serverspec'
require 'net/ssh'

set :backend, :ssh

describe port(8080) do
  it { should be_listening }
end

describe port(8081) do
  it { should be_listening }
end
```

When I execute my test command **rake spec**
The output shows there were No examples found after it cycles through all servers in my list.
What am I doing wrong here?

**Output:**

```
-bash-4.2$ rake spec
/usr/bin/ruby -I/home/username/.gem/ruby/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib:/home/username/.gem/ruby/gems/rspec-support-3.8.0/lib /home/username/.gem/ruby/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\{base,server1\}/\*_spec.rb
**No examples found.**

Finished in 0.00041 seconds (files took 0.50682 seconds to load)
**0 examples, 0 failures**

/usr/bin/ruby -I/home/username/.gem/ruby/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib:/home/username/.gem/ruby/gems/rspec-support-3.8.0/lib /home/username/.gem/ruby/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\{base,server2\}/\*_spec.rb
**No examples found.**

Finished in 0.00036 seconds (files took 0.05545 seconds to load)
**0 examples, 0 failures**
```

**Gems installed:**

```
diff-lcs-1.3
multi_json-1.13.1
net-scp-1.2.1
net-ssh-3.2.0
net-telnet-0.1.1
rake-12.3.2
rspec-3.8.0
rspec-core-3.8.0
rspec-expectations-3.8.2
rspec-its-1.2.0
rspec-mocks-3.8.0
rspec-support-3.8.0
serverspec-2.41.3
sfl-2.3
specinfra-2.76.9
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the way your Rakefile is designed (here it is with indentation corrected):

```ruby
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

hosts = %w(
  server1
)

task :spec => 'spec:all'

namespace :spec do
  task :all => hosts.map {|h| 'spec:' + h.split('.')[0] }
  hosts.each do |host|
    short_name = host.split('.')[0]
    role       = short_name.match(/[^0-9]+/)[0]

    desc "Run serverspec to #{host}"
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(short_name) do |t|
      ENV['TARGET_HOST'] = host
      t.pattern = "spec/{base,#{role}}/*_spec.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

It seems to me that you should not have those examples in `spec_helper.rb` but rather you should have a file `spec/base/base_spec.rb` like this:

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'

describe port(8080) do
  it { should be_listening }
end

describe port(8081) do
  it { should be_listening }
end
```

The idea would be that these tests are run for all hosts and then role-specific tests would be found in `spec/role/myrole_spec.rb`.

Generally, you should not put examples in `spec/spec_helper.rb`.